# How to vlookup in text files with Powershell

Tags: powershell, search, text, comparator

I have 2 txt files:

ConfigurationFile:

```
ABC_LKC_FW_PATH:  \\PathToABCFolder
QWE_LKC_MW_PATH:  \\PathToQWEFolder
DEF_BKC_FW_PATH:  \\PathToDEFFolder
ERT_BKC_MW_PATH:  \\PathToERTcFolder
```

and the other with parameters

ChoosenConfig:

```
ABC_LKC_FW_PATH
ERT_BKC_MW_PATH
```

My script reads and parses the configuration file to name and value.
I need to read from the ChoosenConfig file and use the value of the string in the ConfigurationFile.

No idea how to do it...

Script so far:

```
$IniFile_NME = "$SmokeTestFolder\SanityTests\Config\ConfigToParse.ini"
dir $IniFile_NME

$InputFile = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$IniFile_NME")

while ($InputRecord = $InputFile.ReadLine()) {
    # Display the current record
    Write-Host "`$InputRecord=$InputRecord"
    Write-Host ""

    # Determine the position of the sign (:)
    $Pos = $InputRecord.IndexOf(':')
    Write-Host "`$Pos=$Pos"

    # Determine the length of the record
    $Len = $InputRecord.Length
    Write-Host "`$Len=$Len"

    # Parse the record
    $Variable_NME = $InputRecord.Substring(0, $Pos)
    $VariableValue_STR = $InputRecord.Substring($Pos + 1, $Len -$Pos -1).ToUpper()

    Write-Host "`$Variable_NME=$Variable_NME"
    Write-Host "`$VariableValue_STR=$VariableValue_STR"

    # Create a new variable based on the parsed information
    New-Variable -Force -Name $Variable_NME -Value $VariableValue_STR.Trim()

   # new-variable -name $Variable_NME -value $VariableValue_STR
   Get-Variable -Name $Variable_NME
}
$InputFile.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to look up some value by another value the datastructure of choice is a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx). Split your input at colons followed by whitespace (`:\s*`) and fill the hashtable like this:

```
$configs = @{}
Get-Content $IniFile_NME | ForEach-Object {
    $key, $value = $_ -split ':\s*'
    $configs[$key] = $value
}
```

Another option would be to use `ConvertFrom-StringData`. For that you need to transform the content of the INI file to a single string where the keys and values are separated by `=` instead of `:`.

```
$configs = (Get-Content $IniFile_NME -Raw) -replace ':\s*', '=' |
           ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Use `Get-Content $IniFile_NME | Out-String` instead of `Get-Content $IniFile_NME -Raw` if you're still using PowerShell v2 or earlier.

Once you have the data in a hashtable, you can look up your configs like this:

```
Get-Content $chosenConfigsFile | ForEach-Object { $configs[$_] }
```